# Self Nesting of Array Items at n level, based on the property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have **lenearArray** and **nestingForFilter** array. Based on the barray Items I want Output like **OutputArrary**.

Note: 1. Nesting should be for item where **isParent = true**.

2. Adding nested item in **Or** property.

I have tried few solution but not able to come close to this output.

```
let lenearArray: any[] = [
{ filter: 'name', type: 'contains', isParent: true },
{ filter: 'age', type: 'contains' },
{ filter: 'gender', type: 'contains' },
{ filter: 'address', type: 'contains' }];

let nestingForFilter: string[] = [ 'age', 'gender' ];
```

```
let outputArray: any[] = [ 
{ filter: 'name', type: 'contains', isParent: true, 
or: { 
       filter: 'age', type: 'contains', 
        or: { 
              filter: 'gender', type:'contains'
            }
    } 
},
{ filter: 'address', type: 'contains' }
]
```

Comment: The `outputArray` at : `or: { { filter: 'age'...} }` does not appear to be valid. An object must always have a key-value pair; and here the object with key `or` has a value which is not a valid javascript object, as per my limited understanding.

Comment: updated nested or object values as per @jsN00b comments

Comment: What should be the behaviour if there are 10 (or 15 or 20 or 50) objects in the `lenearArray` with 3 or 4 or 5 (or 15, or 20) objects which have `isParent` as `true`? Should the `nestingForFilter` elements be nested in each parent?

Comment: As per requirement there will always be 1 isParent = true. But that can be at any index in lenearArray

Comment: okay. Suppose the `isParent` is on the 3rd array elt (and totally there are 4), what should be the output? In the above example, if the only `isParent` is on `gender`, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to find inner-most object without 'or' key
const findLast = ob => ob.or ? findLast(ob.or) : ob;

// transform input array to desired target structure
const myTransform = (mainArr, nestElts) => (
  [].concat([{
    // the "only" parent (like "name") is included in the target
    ...mainArr.filter(({ isParent = false }) => isParent)[0],
    // nested "or" keys with corresponding values are added
    ...(
      mainArr.filter(     // filter to exclude "isParent" and "non nestElts"
        ({ filter, isParent }) => (
          !isParent && nestElts.includes(filter)
        )
      ).reduce(           // ".reduce()" to build the nested "or" structure
        (acc, {...props}) => {      // like "age" and "gender"
          const lastChild = findLast(acc);
          lastChild.or = {...props};
          return acc;
        },
        {}
      )
    )
  }]).concat(     // finally, include all "non parent", "non nested" elements
    //  (like "address")
    mainArr.filter(({ filter, isParent }) => (
      !isParent && !(nestElts.includes(filter)))
    )
  )
);

let lenearArray = [
{ filter: 'name', type: 'contains', isParent: true },
{ filter: 'age', type: 'contains' },
{ filter: 'gender', type: 'contains' },
{ filter: 'address', type: 'contains' }];

let nestingForFilter = [ 'age', 'gender' ];

console.log(
  'nested array:\n',
  myTransform(lenearArray, nestingForFilter)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.